# responseText from XMLHttpRequest contains 'Array ( ) ' at the beginning

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

From my JavaScript client side I make a request to my PHP server which I expect response in JSON like below:

```
{"rsp":{"x":"y","w":[{"z":"a","d...
```

PHP code producing the response:

```
public function getResponse() {
    return json_encode($this->getListFromDB());
}

public function getListFromDB() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
    $myArray = array();
    if ($result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnection, $sql)) {
        $tempArray = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
        }
    }

    return $myArray;
}
```

On the PHP side I print out the result I will be sending to client after passing through `json_encode()` and I get:

```
{"rsp":{"x":"y","w":[{"z":"a","d...
```

As expected.

On JavaScript side however when I print the response as below:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.write(this.responseText);
      }
};
```

I get:

```
Array ( ) {"rsp":{"x":"y","w":[{"z":"a","d...
```

This of course will cause the JSON parser to fail.

Why do I get the "**Array ( )** " at the beginning of my response? Is it a client side issue?

** **ISSUE FOUND** **

I was calling `print_r()` on an array at some point before generating the response. This was getting appended to the beginning of the response.

Comment: What is the exact code you use on the php side?

Comment: What exactly does the PHP code look like? And you can see the actual HTTP response content via your browser debug console.

Comment: Will update the question with exact code on php side.

Comment: Without seeing the PHP code you can't exactly tell but it looks like there is a var_dump of an empty array... If you could put all the PHP code would definitely help debug...

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge: Where is `getResponse` called?

Comment: Where do you actually output the json? There are more things going on in your code that we have no idea about.

Comment: hmm var_dump of empty array. That's interesting let me check the code again.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `echo getResponse();` in `index.php`

Comment: What is strange is that if I print to log what `getResponse()` returns there is no **Array ( )**. But on JavaScript side I see it...

Comment: `getResponse()` seems to be a class method, though, so it's probably something like `echo $someClass->getResponse();`, no?. Regardless, you've only showing us a couple of methods. If you have some var_dump or similar, it happens _before_ this...

Comment: @Griffin Most likely you have a var_dump somewhere before all that... Or in some include...

Comment: Right, found the issue. There was a `print_r()` somewhere before that. Thanks!